# AccessDenied when calling the PutObject operation in code build operation when copying files from code commit repository to cross account s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-kms

**Use case:** Sync files from Beta code commit repository to Prod S3 bucket (us-east-1) using aws code pipeline with code commit and code build stages (us-west-2). The buildspec.yml file has commands to copy/sync files from code commit to s3 buckets.

**Error: upload failed:** jam/bie/core_pipeline/folding.json to s3://temp-bucket-aev/temp/folding.json An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

The error does not exist if I change the bucket encryption type to server side encryption with Amazon s3 managed keys (SSE-S3) but error comes back when the encryption type is SSE-KMS.

---

## **A. Beta Account: xxxxxxxxxx**

**A.1. IAM Role:** cicdBuildRole

**A.1.1 IAM Policy:** s3crossaccountaccess_temp

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::temp-bucket-aev/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "<prod_account_number>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**A.1.2 IAM Policy:** cross_account_access_for_code_build

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:role/cicdCrossAccountRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**A.1.3 IAM Managed Policies:** AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSCodeCommitReadOnly, AWSCodeBuildReadOnlyAccess

**A.1.4 Trust Relationship:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**A.2 : Role : codePipelineServiceRole**

***IAM policy: CodePipelineRolePolicy***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject*",
                "s3:GetBucket*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:Abort*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::artifact-beta-cicd-us-west-2",
                "arn:aws:s3:::artifact-beta-cicd-us-west-2/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:role/pipeline-beta-CIC-CodePipelineSourceCodeCo-1R53MXYY2ECRC",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:role/pipeline-beta-CIC-CodePipelineBuildCodeBui-73K6MQ3LCRG7",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

***Trust Relationship:***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**A.3 : buildspec.yml :**

```
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Sync files from the CodeCommit repo to the S3 bucket."

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Syncing changed files from CodeCommit repo to S3 bucket in the Beta account..."

      # Copy files from CodeCommit repo to S3 bucket in the Prod account
      - echo "Syncing files from CodeCommit repo to S3 bucket in the Prod account..."
      - aws s3 sync jam/bie/core_pipeline/ s3://temp-bucket-aev/temp/ --region us-east-1

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```

---

## **Prod Account: yyyyyyyyyyy**

**S3 Bucket:** arn:aws:s3:::temp-bucket-aev

**IAM Role:** cicdCrossAccountRole

**IAM policy:** temp_policy_code_pipeline

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:List*",
                "codecommit:Get*",
                "codecommit:GitPull",
                "codebuild:StartBuild",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-west-2:<beta-account-number>:CodeRepo",
                "arn:aws:s3:::temp-bucket-aev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Bucket Policy:** temp-bucket-aev

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCrossAccountAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<beta-account-number>:role/cicdBuildRole"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::temp-bucket-aev/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::temp-bucket-aev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

***Encryption type:***

Server-side encryption with AWS Key Management Service keys (SSE-KMS)

***KMS Key Policy:*** (arn: arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:<prod_account_number>:key/zzz-zzzz-000-2222-ttttttt)

**Key policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "key-policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndCICDAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:role/cicdCrossAccountRole",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:DescribeKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<prod_account_number>:root"
            },
            "Action": "kms:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCloudWatchLogsAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt*",
                "kms:Decrypt*",
                "kms:ReEncrypt*",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
                "kms:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:logs:arn": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:*:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I change the bucket encryption type to server side encryption with Amazon s3 managed keys (SSE-S3) but error comes back when the encryption type is SSE-KMS.

Modified the key policy and experimented a lot with different policy combination.

Answer (score 0):

So it doesn't look like your 'cicdBuildRole' has KMS permissions on the production KMS Key, so when it's trying to upload to S3 it has the permissions to connect to the account and S3, but not the permissions to encrypt the objects using KMS.

Try adding this to your policy to give your beta account role the perms to use KMS:

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowBetaAccountCICDRoleAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<beta_account_number>:role/cicdBuildRole"
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting the error:

fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Comment: I cannot add the above policy as it throws the error - Has prohibited field Principal.

Comment: Maybe if you change the Principal config to this it might stop the prohibited error:

`"Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<beta_account_number>:role/cicdBuildRole"
}`

Your access denied error for S3 is likely because you need more permissions for a sync operation. If you add `s3:DeleteObject` & `s3:GetBucketLocation` to your BucketPolicy it should fix your issue. As for a sun operation you need the three permissions you have, plus the two extra above.